# MQTT Client for node.js playloads larger than 128 bytes

Tags: node.js, websocket, mqtt

I try to understand and implement the MQTT-Client for node.js, which can be found at: http://jahbromo.blogspot.de/2011/12/client-mqttt-javascript.html

When I publish playloads lower than 128 bytes there's no problem and the message gets directed correctly, but when the payload is larger, node.js prints out "Connection closed by broker" right after the publishing. Because i'm relatively new to websockets and node.js I don't understand why this node.js-server-implemenatation mentioned above can't handle playloads larger than 128 bytes.
Because I need to send larger payloads, it would be great if someone could help me to increase the limitation.

Thanks.

Comment: I've been working on an MQTT client/server library for a while now, and it supports quite a few things that yilun's doesn't, such as qos and long messages. Available at https://github.com/adamvr/MQTT.js Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You'll notice down in the limitations of the code you link to (which is actually a modified version of https://github.com/yilun/node_mqtt_client ):

> Can not handle payloads larger than 128 byte.

This is a limitation of the client library, not of MQTT.

To add support for larger payloads, you need to implement full "remaining length" support for the PUBLISH packet as described in the spec: http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/dw/webservices/ws-mqtt/mqtt-v3r1.html#fixed-header

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. So that means I have to change the code for the "fix header" from line 199 to 208, right? `buffer[i++] = MQTTPUBLISH;
        buffer[i++] = payload.length + var_header.length;
        for (n = 0; n < var_header.length; n++) {
            buffer[i++] = var_header[n];
        }
        for (n = 0; n < payload.length; n++) { //Insert payloads
            buffer[i++] = payload.charCodeAt(n);
        }` But how do I reserve four bytes for the payload?

Comment: Yes. You'd need to calculate in advance how many bytes are required for the "remaining length" and add that to the size of buffer.

Comment: Okay, but I thought this is already done by line 197: `var buffer = new Buffer(2+var_header.length+payload.length);` where the buffer is initialized by the length of the var_header and the length of the payload.

Comment: "Fixed header" means fixed format, not fixed length. The code assumes that remaining length is always 1 byte and this limits you to a 128 byte payload. You can see how I dealt with this in the publish function right at the bottom of http://mosquitto.org/js/mosquitto-1.1.js